# Run unbound groovy script in gmaven

Tags: groovy, maven, gmaven-plugin

According to [documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code#ExecutingGroovyCode-ExecuteaLocalGroovyScript), it is possible to bind a groovy script to a phase of maven lifecycle, but how do I run it "unbound" ?
In other words, I want to do the following thing

Declare my groovy script to use :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>${pom.basedir}/src/main/script/myscript.groovy</source>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then invoke it directly from command-line (outside of any lifecycle).
But how do I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> mvn org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:execute
```

note that if you want to select different scripts from the commandline, you have to define different configurations each one in a profile and pick the profile instead.

Answer (score 0):

It was extremely excruciating to fiddle with GMaven on eclipse I found a best ever solution here on my git hub using maven eclipse plug in https://github.com/mukadder/groovygmaven.git